# How to merge two queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query in PostgresSQL that returns monthly sales count by given date range.

I have 2 queries -- 1 returns sales count, and another returns list of months by date range (start date and end date)

Query 1: (This returns sales count)

```
SELECT count(overall_sl) total_sales, count(CASE WHEN overall_sl < value_1 THEN 1 END) faled_sales
            FROM  (
                SELECT overall_sl, value_1
                FROM   combined c 
                GROUP  BY dept_name, date_updated, date, overall_sl, no_addons,  
                value_1, category_id, subcategory_id, branch_name
              ) sales;

Output:
total sales     failed_sales
----------------------------
1047            54
```

Query 2: (This returns list of months for given two dates)

```
WITH date_ranges AS (
    SELECT 
      min(date_trunc('month', timestamp '2018-01-01')) min_start,
      max(date_trunc('month', timestamp '2018-12-11'))  max_end
    )
    SELECT 
       ser.month::DATE as st_month,
       (date_trunc('month', ser.month::DATE) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date as end_month,

       0 as total_sales,
       0 as failed_sales
    FROM date_ranges AS dr,
         generate_series(min_start, max_end, '1 month') AS ser(month) 

Output:
st_date     end_date   total_sales    failed_sales
----------  ----------  ----------    ------------
2018-01-01  2018-01-31  0             0
2018-02-01  2018-02-28  0             0
```

I need to join these queries as shown in this image below

[image: Query]

How can I write this query in Postgres SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
with cte as
(
SELECT count(overall_sl) total_sales, count(CASE WHEN overall_sl < value_1 THEN 1 END) faled_sales
            FROM  (
                SELECT overall_sl, value_1
                FROM   combined c 
                GROUP  BY dept_name, date_updated, date, overall_sl, no_addons,  
                value_1, category_id, subcategory_id, branch_name
              ) sales
), 
date_ranges AS 
(
    SELECT 
      min(date_trunc('month', timestamp '2018-01-01')) min_start,
      max(date_trunc('month', timestamp '2018-12-11'))  max_end
),
cte2 as
(
SELECT 
       ser.month::DATE as st_month,
       (date_trunc('month', ser.month::DATE) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date as end_month,

       0 as total_sales,
       0 as failed_sales
    FROM date_ranges AS dr,
         generate_series(min_start, max_end, '1 month') AS ser(month)
) select cte.*,cte2.* from cte join cte2 on cte.total_sales=cte2.total_sales and cte.failed_sales=cte2.failed_sales
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I got no results when I ran this query :(

Comment: 0 as total_sales,
       0 as failed_sales -- are placeholders where actual values should come

Comment: @Showkath use you have got no result because inner join return only when common key exist in both table , as you not mentioned your combined output so i dont what will be your join like left,right or inner

Comment: there is no key between these tables I am afraid. What I expect is -- first query should group the count by month that returned by second query. Second query returns start date and end date of all months in that given date range